# Storage API: ¿Diferencia entre localStorage.setItem('user','juan' ) y localStorage.user = 'juan'?

Tags: javascript, api, local-storage

Un saludo. Me encuentro investigando el localStorage, supe que se podía trabajar de dos maneras los datos que se guardan en el:

```
localStorage.setItem('user','juan');
localStorage.user = 'juan';

localStorage.getItem('user);
localStorage.user;
```

En los sitios que he investigado no sugieren alguna diferencia en cuanto al uso de una manera u otra para asignar y llamar datos de la localStorage. Mi pregunta es si realmente existe alguna diferencia, y si no entonces cual de las dos formas es la más indicada para usar o la que más se use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage.user = 'juan';` podría generar conflictos si tuvieras nombres como las propiedades del localStorage (ej: `localStorage.clear` , `localStorage.length`), mientras que si no hay nada en el localStorage ocurriría lo siguiente:

- `localStorage.getItem('juan')` sería `null`.
- `localStorage.user` sería `undefined`.

De igual forma si revisas la documentación de MDN verás que usan get y set, así que seria una buena practica utilizarlos por lo mismo.

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)